# PHP8 で cairo 機能拡張をインストールしたい

Tags: php

http://php.adamharvey.name/manual/ja/class.cairo.php

https://pecl.php.net/package/cairo

PHPから cairo を利用したいのですがpeclに公開されているのはバージョン5のままサポートが止まっていて
現行のバージョン8ではコンパイルが通りません。

FFI での利用も難しそうです。

何らかの方法で、PHP8 で cairo を組み込む方法を御存知の方はいらっしゃいませんでしょうか？

追記：

https://github.com/swen100/php-cairo

こちらを見つけてビルドしてみましたが、

```
/usr/local/src/cairo/php-cairo-php8/src/pattern.c:23:10: fatal error: ext/eos_datastructures/php_eos_datastructures_api.h: No such file or directory
   23 | #include <ext/eos_datastructures/php_eos_datastructures_api.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

やはりエラーになってしまいました。

Comment: https://github.com/gtkforphp/cairo/issues/40　によると、php8 と php8.1 で非互換の修正が行われてしまったようです